# Delimiter after a quoted field, how to escape quote

Tags: sql, parsing, delimiter, quotes, exasol

I have that kind of file

```
info1;info2;info3";info4;info5
```

And after parsing I have that error

`Error: [42636] ETL-2106: Error while parsing row=0 (starting from 0) [CSV Parser found at byte 5 (starting with 0 at the beginning of the row) of 5 a field delimiter after an quoted field (with an additional whitespace) in file '~/path'. Please check for correct enclosed fields, valid field separators and e.g. unescaped field delimiters that are contained in the data (these have to be escaped)]`

I'm sure that the reason is here info3"; but how can I solve this problem I have no idea

Also I can't rid of quotes, because it should be in report

The main part of python code is

```
 # Transform data to valid CSV format: remove BOM, remove '=' sign, remove repeating quotes in Size column
    decoded_csv = r.content.decode('utf-8').replace(u'\ufeff', '').replace('=', '')
    
    print(decoded_csv)
    
    cr = csv.reader(decoded_csv.splitlines(), delimiter=';')
    lst = list(cr)[1:]

    f = csv.writer(open(base_folder + 'txt/' + shop, "w+"), delimiter=';')
    for row in lst:
        f.writerow(row[:-2])
```

After this code I get that kind of file

```
info1;info2;"info3""";info4;info5
```

And it is not what I need
But when I change code a little by adding "quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, quotechar='')"

```
  # Transform data to valid CSV format: remove BOM, remove '=' sign, remove repeating quotes in Size column
    decoded_csv = r.content.decode('utf-8').replace(u'\ufeff', '').replace('=', '')
    
    print(decoded_csv)
    
    cr = csv.reader(decoded_csv.splitlines(), delimiter=';')
    lst = list(cr)[1:]

    f = csv.writer(open(base_folder + 'txt/' + shop, "w+"), delimiter=';' quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, quotechar='')
    for row in lst:
        f.writerow(row[:-2])
```

I get what I need

```
info1;info2;info3";info4;info5
```

It is a 2nd step (exasol) and code returned the error

```
MERGE INTO hst AS dst
USING (
    SELECT DISTINCT
      ar,
      ar_na,
    FROM (
        IMPORT INTO
        (
            ar                  VARCHAR(100) UTF8 COMMENT IS 'ar',
            ar_na           VARCHAR(100) UTF8 COMMENT IS 'ar na',
        
        )
        FROM CSV /*SS:R*/
        AT '&1'
        USER '&2'
        IDENTIFIED BY '&3'
        FILE '~/path'
        SKIP = 0
        ROW SEPARATOR = 'CRLF'
        COLUMN SEPARATOR = ';'
        TRIM
     )
    GROUP BY
        ar,
        ar_na,
        
) src ON src.ar = dst.ar

WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
    dst.ar_na = src.ar_na,
    
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (
        ar
        ar_na,      
)
VALUES (
        src.ar,
        src.ar_na,

);
```

If file looks like `info1;info2;info3;info4;info5` everything works fine, all scripts work

Comment: Can you please post the code that returned the error? It'll make it a lot easier to help you out.

Comment: added code, hope it will help

Comment: It would help more if you identified what tool you are using (or which SQL variant, if that's SQL). And why did you tag your question [tag:python]?

Comment: I added python because at first python prepares file - rid off quotes “info1”;”info2”;”info3”””;”info4” and than on 2nd step in exasol I got the error

Comment: @CyclikP: OK, I changed the python tag to exasol, which is surely much more relevant to the error. Although it's quite possible that you would get a better response if you show the entire processing pipeline, starting with the original file. (Why do you need to strip the spaces at all? Doesn't exasol's CSV parser handle quotes?)

Comment: @rici also added part of python code and clarify what I do and what I get after every step, the main problem that If I delete all quotes info1;info2;info3;info4;info5 everything works well, but when I left one quotes, I get the error

Comment: Did you try just leaving `info1;info2;"info3""";info4;info5` in the CSV file? It looks to me like Exasol is supposed to handle that correctly (i.e. interpret the third field as `info3"`). Certainly, removing the quotes is not going to produce the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Exaosl treats double quotes (") as column **delimiter**. This enables you to specify values that contain the column **separator** (in your case that's the semicolon). See the entry "Special characters" in the [documentation](https://docs.exasol.com/db/latest/loading_data/file_formats.htm#CSV_Data_Format).

You have two options here:

1. Disable the column delimiter by passing `COLUMN DELIMITER = ''` to the import statement.
2. Duplicate all double quotes in the csv file. Exasol ignores the column delimiter if it occurs twice consecutively.